# nginx as udp reverse proxy with api endpoint

Tags: nginx, config, nginx-reverse-proxy

How do I have to create my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf for both DNS Loadbalancing and using the ReST-API? The Loadbalancing works fine, though. But creating an api endpoint does not function as I thought it should be.

When I try to start the service, it fails with this error message:

> "nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "api" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:27".

My config file so far:

```
stream {
  upstream dns_servers {
    server 127.0.0.2:53 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server 127.0.0.3:53 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
  }
  server {
    listen 53 udp;
    proxy_pass dns_servers;
  }
}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    location /api {
      api write=on;
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny  all;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out `api write=on;`?

Comment: Now nginx is running. Of course no API. My intention was to add servers to the dns_servers group via api call.

Comment: Assuming you have nginx plus installed